# To return the list in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, list

Below is my code,

```
List<string> modified_listofstrings = new List<string>();
string sJSON = "";
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer jSearializer =
                 new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
resulted_value = final_resulted_series_name + ":" + period_name + ":" + period_final_value;
modified_listofstrings.Add(resulted_value);
json_resultedvalue = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resulted_value);
modified_listofstrings.Add(json_resultedvalue);
sJSON = jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
return sJSON;
```

But on following line ,

```
sJSON = jSearializer.Serialize(modified_listofstrings);
```

I am getting an error as Cannot implicitly convert type string to system.collection.generic.list

Comment: And what is `jSearializer` in the above?

Comment: what is jSerializer.Serialize() expecting as argument?

Comment: @Reshma gentle nudge: the questions above are important context to the question; without that it is very hard to comment. In particular, the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` looks like `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` (json.net), but that `Serialize` API (on the erroring line) does not match anything `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer` offers. So: *what is that*?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question, I have updated my question above but my issue is resolved but I guess my JSON in resulted_value doesnot give valid JSON format, I am having trouble with its format.

Comment: @Reshma the entire point of a serializer is that *it* worries about the format... but it wants an object in, not a string. Can you give an example of "here's the input", "here's the expected output"...?

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand you, what example you wants me to give you , can't I pass this resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}"; to serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resulted_value = final_resulted_series_name + ":" + period_name + ":" + period_final_value;
```

This is not a valid JSON. It must have key, value format separated by comma. I guess it should be:

```
resulted_value = "{series_name : \"" + final_resulted_series_name + "\",period_name: \"" + period_name + "\",period_final_value: \"" + period_final_value + "\"}";
```

so the result should be something like this:

> {series_name: "whatever_series_name_is", period_name:
>   "whatever_period_name_is",period_final_value:
>   "whatever_period_final_value_is"}

Comment: Since the OP is running `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` on the composed string, my interpretation is that it is ***not intended*** to be JSON - that is the opaque payload. Of course, what it means to JSON-serialize a naked string is anyone's guess... (it looks like JSON.NET just passes it through untouched)

Comment: This worked but I guess I am unable to place double quotes properly besides values, it's showing double quotes along with backward slash.I am trying for it but if you get the answer to my solution I will be very grateful to you,

Answer (score 2):

Let me fix your approach - instead of building JSON strings using your data, and then putting them into a list and trying again to serialize that, what you should do is build your data structure and then serialize it in one go.

Since I couldn't figure out the structure of the data in your post, here is an example with a different format:

```
public struct Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public List<string> FavoriteBands;
}
```

The easiest way to serialize it is to use [Newtonsoft JSON](http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/). If you have an object called `person`, then you would serialize it using

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
```

Now suppose you have a list of these objects i.e. `List<Person> people = GetTheListFromSomewhere();`, then you would serialize it using

```
string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(people);
```

Go ahead and try it!

Comment: This. Oh so much this.